# Responsive tooltip in CSS

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, tooltip, responsive

I have made a tooltip on hover over an icon and it works fine in desktop view.

**Working Snippet:**

```css
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.tooltip img {
  width: 15px;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext[data-position="bottom"] {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 400px;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 0.5rem;
  border-width: 1px;
  border-color: #e2e8f0;
  padding: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<label> Some Label </label>

  <span className="ml-2">
    <div class="tooltip">
      <img
        src="https://www.svgrepo.com/show/2297/doubts-button.svg"
        alt="help text"
      />
      <span data-position="bottom" class="tooltiptext">
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
        industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever
        since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
        scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five
        centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining
        essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release
        of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently
        with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions
        of Lorem Ipsum.
      </span>
    </div>
  </span>
```

Whereas in mobile view, this leads to horizontal scroll bar.

Please switch to mobile view to see the issue.

[image]

**Things I tried:**

I have tried removing `margin-left` and modified `left` value like,

```
.tooltip .tooltiptext[data-position="bottom"] {

  visibility: hidden;
  width: 400px;
  .
  .
  .
  .
  .
  left: 0%;
  margin-left: 0px;
}
```

But this doesn't work... Kindly please help me to make this tooltip responsive in mobile devices using CSS. Big thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the following css:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 576px) {
            .tooltiptext {
                width: 300px;
            }
        }
```